# How to tell which version of visual studio is building my project?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, msbuild

We just spent a few days debugging mysterious build failures on our automated build machine, only to find that the WRONG version of visual studio was being used to build with.

Instead of VS 2012 Update 3, the automated build was using Update 1 or 2 (Or no update at all).

So what can I use to check that the correct version of VS is being invoked?

I would like to add a test at the beginning of the build that aborts the build with an informative error (If the wrong version of VS is invoked).

Note: This is not an issue of merely detecting _MSC_VER in code, but I want to enforce using VS Update 3.
I tried looking in my build log (set to diagnostic) to find anything, and all I found was this, which was not very helpful:

- VisualStudioDir = C:\Users...\Documents\Visual Studio 2012
- VisualStudioEdition = Microsoft Visual Studio Ultimate 2012
- VisualStudioVersion = 11.0

Comment: Though by all means if a macro like _MSC_VER can give me the answer I'll accept that as an acceptable solution.

Comment: Why are you building with devenv?  And not msbuild.exe?

Comment: I do build with msbuild.exe

Comment: But portions of our build are farmed out to devenv.

Comment: Since Framework 2.0, there really isn't a reason to use devenv.exe to build your code.  IMHO.

Comment: some fudgewit devs insist on using vdproj's though.<sigh>